# How to access calendars from an application without needed to ask for email account and password?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

I want to develop an application to access some caledars in a google account.

My idea is to just set the google account, myaccount@gmail.com and the application can connect. The only requirement would be to go to the google account and give access to my application. In this way I can install the application for many users and they don't need to do anything.

It is how the addon [caldav synchronizer](https://caldavsynchronizer.org/download-2/) works.

So for that, I create a service account in my google account, and I use this code to try to create the calendar service:

```cs
public CalendarService GetCalendarServiceServiceAccount(string paramStrPathCertificado, string paramStrEmailServiceAccount, string[] paramScopes)
{
    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(paramStrPathCertificado, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

    ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
        new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(paramStrEmailServiceAccount)
            {
                Scopes = paramScopes,
            }.FromCertificate(certificate));


    CalendarService micalendarService = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "My Calendars"
        });

        return micalendarService;
}
```

Then to get the calendars I use this code:

```cs
var dummyService = GetCalendarServiceServiceAccount("credentials2.p12", "myCalendars@XXX.gserviceaccount.com", ScopesParaModificar);
IEnumerable<CalendarListEntry> dummyCalendarios = dummyService.CalendarList.List().Execute().Items;
```

And the scopes:

```cs
static string[] ScopesParaModificar = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, CalendarService.Scope.CalendarEvents };
```

The problem is that I don't get calendars.

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33473974/google-api-v3-cant-get-list-of-calendars), the answer says that in my google account, I should add the user of the service account to my calendar, but it doesn't work, I can't get calendars. Also this solution isn't really what I am looking for, because I don't want to have to add this service account to my calendar. In the caldav synchronizer I don't need to add any user of my calendar, just set my google account that has the calendars as user and then allow the application as trusted application.

So how could I access my calendar only stating my google account and give permission to the application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## sharing with a service account

In order for a service account to access a calendar. The owner of the calendar which is most often the developer of the application.  Will take the service account email address and share the calendar with the service account.   This is done though the Web ui as you would any other user.

Once the calendar is shared with the service account it will be able to access it.

## what is calendarlist.

The CalendarList.List is used to request a list of the calendars the user has add to their CalendarList.  The calendar list is simply a UI element in the google calendar web application.  It appears at the bottom left of the Google calendar web UI

[image]

In the Google calendar web application when you create a new calendar it is automatically added the users calendar list.  If a calendar is shared with you it is often times added there as well. (i have found this to be buggy)

However if you share a calendar with a service account as it does not have a UI element they are not automatically added.  This is why the service accounts calendarlist.list returns empty.

If you want to add a calendar to the service accounts calendar list then you will need to do a [calendarlist.insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendarList/insert) and add it manually.

## What you should be doing.

> I want to develop an application to access some caledars in a google account.

Who owns the calendars that you want to access.  If its you then you should be using a service account.

If the calendars are owned by other users then you will need to use Oauth2 and authorize the user to access their data you should not be using service accounts for this use case.  Using Oauth2 have your users authorize your application store the refresh token, and then use the refresh token in the future to access their calendar.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But I still have a doubt. In the caldav add on, I install the add on in the user. In the synchronizer, I only have to give the email of the owner of the calendars and then go to the account of the owner of the calendar and give access to the add on. But I have to do this once, Then I can install to another user, just give he email of the owner of the calendar and I can access to the calendars. So I don't need to shared calendar with Google service.

Comment: Cant tell you how the addon works you could try contacting the owners and asking them.  I can only tell you how the google calendar api works.

Comment: "If you want to add a calendar to the service accounts calendar list then you will need to do a calendarlist.insert and add it manually." How could I do the manually insert? I have to create an application to connect to the owner account of canledear and do the insert in the service account?

Comment: You cant add it manually exactly you need to manually do it using the calendarlist.insert method.  Create them a endpoint in your application where they can add it.    If you are not the owner of this account you should not be using service accounts.

Comment: The mention of OAuth2 in the last section can be confusing, since authorization with a service account is also considered OAuth2, albeit 2-legged instead of 3-legged https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account. I'd suggest editing out those mentions.

Comment: @lamblichus I'm not sure which section you are referring to the only section i mention Oauth2 is actually suggesting that they go with the normal 3 legged oauth2 if its user data and not a calendar they control.   Service accounts should only be used when the developer owns the account.   They should not be asking others to grant a service account access to their data.  Its a security issue with ensuring that two users don't see each others data.